# Android Studio does not recognize 'MediaProjectionManager' class

Tags: android, mediaprojectionmanager

I am trying to make an app for screenshot. I've found there are several guides for using `MediaProjectionManager` for that purpose.

This is one of them.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/

I copied the source exactly but the Android studio just can't handle the `MediaProjectionManager`.

These are the build error messages.

`Error:(23, 32) error: package android.media.projection does not exist`

`Error:(24, 32) error: package android.media.projection does not exist`

`Error:(32, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MediaProjectionManager`

`Error:(35, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MediaProjection`

`Error:(171, 66) error: package MediaProjection does not exist`

And these are the lines that are causing the error.

`import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;`

`import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;`

I'm sure these class paths for `MediaProjection` and `MediaProjectionManager` are correct. A little help please.

Answer (score 0):

MediaProjection is added in API level 21 (Android 5.0). The "compileSdkVersion" of your Module needs to >= 21.
e.g

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it resolves the problem. Thank you, @KnightMobile.